# Start ESS process in R script

Tags: r, emacs, ess

I've got the following problem in my Emacs (i am a complete newby and way far from LISP programming): When i open a .R file, no ESS process is starting. This is a problem because i want to configure TAB-completion and see R Documentation in scripts.

This is the Error message:"No ESS process associated with current buffer
"
This is only the case in .R files. When starting inferior ESS i dont have this problem. (hope i got this right: M-x R starts a process und Emacs and is therefore called inferior?)

My .emacs is cofigured like this:

```
(require 'auto-complete)
(require 'auto-complete-config)
(require 'ess-stata-mode)
(require 'ess-eldoc)
(add-hook 'inferior-ess-mode-hook 'ess-use-eldoc)
(autoload 'R-mode "ess-site.el" "" t)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.R\\'" . R-mode))
```

Those two lines above should start ESS in script, shouldn't they?

```
(global-auto-complete-mode t)
(setq  ess-tab-complete-in-script t)
(setq ess-use-auto-complete 't)
(setq ess-use-eldoc 't)
(setq ess-use-company 't)
```

And I included ElDoc and AC to get Autocompletion. 
I want to get to see the [Documentation](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ESSAuto-complete) of R in Emacs.
I'd really appreciate your help. What did I miss?
Greetings and Thanks in advance

Comment: you won't see the the documentation until you start R with M-x R or the like, since ESS queries the R process for documentation. If you are using `company-mode` (which I suggest) and you have set `ess-use-company`, then you don't need `ess-use-auto-complete`. Those are two alternative completion engines.

Comment: Thank you,for your fast answer! I got that one working once. So i think it is possible to see the documentation in '.R' scripts. But it was more or less coincidence and i am not able to reproduce this (i was playing around in the source code of that package). But you helped me out with the packages. So thanks!

Comment: ESS gets the documentation from the R interpreter. So it must be running for docs in R scripts. You could start R in your ess-mode-hook, it is just added overhead.

Comment: My mistake, misunderstood you. Sry! It is working. Thanks so much!!